# Very Wide Table Spanning Multiple Pages in LaTeX

Tags: tables, longtable

I am writing a two column IEEE paper (standard IEETran). I want to create a table that spans multiple pages in LaTeX. I have tried longtable and that breaks pages rightly. However the problem is my table is also very wide. I can't fix it in the middle of the page. The table moves into and after the right margin. Is there any way that I can move the left side of my table a little bit towards left, so that my whole table is centered according to its total width not from a fixed position.

Answer (score 1):

technically you can, simply set

```
\setlength\LTleft{-1cm}
```

and the left edge of the table will be 1cm into the left margin.

Whether such a setting is acceptable to the journal specifying IEETran formatting is another question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to manage a wide table in that environment is to drop the text size to \footnotesize or \scriptsize e.g.,

```
 {
 \footnotesize
 \newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
 \begin{longtable}{@{}d{2}d{5}d{1}d{7}d{7}d{5}d{10}d{3}@{}}\\*
 .... etc etc
 \end{longtable}
 }
```